# django multilevel nested formsets

Tags: django, forms, nested

django provide inline formset which allow to 3rd level of nesting, but I need much more complex nesting. It should be fully dynamic, so I can go one to one on each level, but it could be one to many on each level. So far I have this only, but could be expanded for additional sublevels.

```
class Srts(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
 

class Volume(models.Model):
    srts = models.ForeignKey('Srts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)


class Qtree(models.Model):
    volume = models.ForeignKey('Volume', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Server(models.Model):
    qtree = models.ForeignKey('Qtree', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)

class CifsPermission(models.Model):
    qtree = models.ForeignKey('Qtree', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, default='None')
    permission = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, default='None')
```

I have been googling a lot last days, but there is not much.

Some examples
[django-nested-inline-formsets-example](https://github.com/philgyford/django-nested-inline-formsets-example) -that basic only 3rd level

[Django-better forms](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html) -could handle multiple forms on one submit, but not formsets

[django-nested-inline](https://pypi.org/project/django-nested-inline/)  -only for admin page

Shoudl be the way to work with not model related form , then do some separation and appropriate logic and then save it to models?

can't add image, some sever error ocured, so giving the link directly
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQFO3.jpg
I would like to to something simular over normal view, not admin view.

update:
I have made this class

```
class BaseMultiFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    inlines = [{'inline_prefix': 'inline_formset'}]

    def add_nested_formsets(self, form):
        for inline in self.inlines:
            (inline_prefix, inline_formset), = inline.items()
            setattr(
                form,
                f'nested_{inline_prefix}',
                inline_formset(
                    instance=form.instance,
                    data=form.data if form.is_bound else None,
                    files=form.files if form.is_bound else None,
                    prefix=self.get_nested_prefix(inline_prefix, form.prefix, inline_formset),
                )
            )

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        self.add_nested_formsets(form)

    def get_nested_prefix(self, inline_prefix, formset_prefix, inline_formset):
        return f'{inline_prefix}-{formset_prefix}-{inline_formset.get_default_prefix()}'

    def is_valid(self):
        result = super().is_valid()

        if self.is_bound:
            for form in self.forms:
                for inline in self.inlines:
                    (inline_prefix, inline_formset), = inline.items()
                    if hasattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}'):
                        result = result and getattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}').is_valid()

        return result

    def save(self, commit=True):
        result = super().save(commit=commit)

        for form in self.forms:
            for inline in self.inlines:
                (inline_prefix, inline_formset), = inline.items()
                if hasattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}'):
                    if not self._should_delete_form(form):
                        getattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}').save(commit=commit)

        return result

    def _is_adding_nested_inlines_to_empty_form(self, form, inline_prefix):
        if not hasattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}'):
            return False

        if is_form_persisted(form):
            return False

        if not is_empty_form(form):
            return False

        non_deleted_forms = set(getattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}').forms).difference(
            set(getattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}').deleted_forms)
        )

        return any(not is_empty_form(nested_form) for nested_form in non_deleted_forms)

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

        for form in self.forms:
            for inline in self.inlines:
                (inline_prefix, inline_formset), = inline.items()
                if not hasattr(form, f'nested_{inline_prefix}') or self._should_delete_form(form):
                    continue

                if self._is_adding_nested_inlines_to_empty_form(form, inline_prefix):
                    form.add_error(
                        field=None,
                        error=(
                            f"You are trying to add {inline_prefix}(s) to a parent which does not yet exist."
                        ),
                    )
```

then form and formsets

```
UserMappingFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Cifs, UserMapping,
    #formset=BaseQtreeFormset,
    form=UserMappingForm,
    fields='__all__', extra=2
)

CifsPermissionFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Cifs, CifsPermission,
    #formset=BaseQtreeFormset,
    form = CifsPermissionForm,
    fields='__all__', extra=2
)


class BaseCifsFormset(BaseMultiFormSet):
    inlines = [
                {'user_mapping': UserMappingFormset},
                {'cifs_permission':CifsPermissionFormset},
    ]


CifsFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Qtree, Cifs,
    form=CifsForm,
    formset=BaseCifsFormset,
    fields='__all__', extra=1
)


NfsFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Qtree, Nfs,
    form=NfsForm,
    #formset=BaseQtreeFormset,
    fields='__all__', extra=3
)

class BaseQtreeFormset(BaseMultiFormSet):
    inlines = [
                {'nfs': NfsFormset},
                {'cifs': CifsFormset},
    ]



QtreeFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Volume, Qtree,
    form=QtreeForm,
    formset=BaseQtreeFormset,
    fields='__all__',
    extra=1
)

class BaseVolumesFormset(BaseMultiFormSet):
    inlines = [
                {'qtree': QtreeFormset},
    ]

VolumeFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Srts,
    Volume,
    form=VolumeForm,
    formset=BaseVolumesFormset,
    fields= '__all__',
    extra=1,
    # If you don't want to be able to delete:
    # can_delete=False
)
```

this is my create view

```
class SrtsCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Srts
    form_class = SrtsForm
    template_name = 'srts/srts_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('srts:srts-list')

    def get_volume_formset(self, data=None, instance=None):
        return VolumeFormset(data=data, instance=instance)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['srts_form'] = context.pop('form')
        if self.request.POST:
            context['volume_forms'] = self.get_volume_formset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['volume_forms'] = self.get_volume_formset()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        srts_form = context['srts_form']
        volume_forms = context['volume_forms']

        if srts_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(srts_form, volume_forms, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(srts_form, volume_forms, **kwargs)



    def form_valid(self, srts_form, volume_forms,  **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = srts_form.save()
            volume_forms.instance = self.object
            if volume_forms.is_valid():
                volume_forms.save()
            else:
                self.form_invalid(srts_form, volume_forms, **kwargs)
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, srts_form, volume_forms,**kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['volume_forms']=volume_forms
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

I was able only to get srts_form saved, not formset , reason was formset.valid()  didn't passed, I make some modification , but still can't get it worked as expected.

Comment: I bet if you duplicate this source [django-nested-inline-formsets-example books.forms](https://github.com/philgyford/django-nested-inline-formsets-example/blob/main/publishing/books/forms.py) and just add another nesting level it'll work. The project says it's just a demonstration, a proof of concept, and from what I'm seeing it just uses `form.nested` which should go up `x` amount of levels if the nested one **also** has a nested

Comment: I thought this is just for 3rd level , but I give a try, keep you posted.